# python server http://0.0.0.0:8080/

Tags: python, server, web.py

I am having a problem using webpy.  Here is my code

```
import web

urls = ('/(.*)', 'hello')
app = web.application(urls, globals())

class hello:        
    def GET(self, name):
        if not name: 
            name = 'World'
        return 'Hello, ' + name + '!'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

When I run it, it starts on `http://0.0.0.0:8080/` and it says I don't have access to localhost, which is `127.0.0.1`.  How can I change it?  I tried `python ./server.py` but this didn't work

Comment: But, if you run `python yourfilename.py`....what message do you have?

Comment: http://localhost:8080...?

Comment: run normly and show :
http://0.0.0.0:8080/

Comment: Are you running python locally, or is it on a remote server. When you say "it says I don't have access to localhost".. who says, your browser?

Comment: yes my browser now i change 0.0.0.0 to localhost and it's working fine thankyou

Comment: What exactly does your browser say? What's the exact error message? And where are you running your web.py app? Are you running it on your own machine? Or are you running it on a server?

Answer (score 3):

When web.py starts up, by default it listens on all IPv4 interfaces, on port 8080. It says this by reporting `http://0.0.0.0:8080/`.

In this context, `0.0.0.0` isn't a real address, so you can't point your browser to that address. You can point your browser to either the "real" address (you may have more than one for the same computer), or to the loopback address `127.0.0.1`, or `localhost`. Loopback only works locally (i.e., your server is on the same computer as your browser/client.)

You can change `web.py`'s default:

```
 host$ python app.py
 http://0.0.0.0:8080/
 ^C
 host$ python app.py 127.0.0.1
 http://127.0.0.1:8080/
 ^C
 host$ python app.py 127.0.0.1:9999
 http://127.0.0.1:9999
 ^C
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem and as @pbuck pointed out you need to run it probably on a loopback address like the localhost:

```
http://localhost:8080
```